# Sharing authentication cookie among Asp.Net Core 1 (MVC6) and MVC 5 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a few MVC 5 applications that share the same authentication cookie. I'm using ASP.NET Identity to create the cookie.

I checking if the user is authenticated using Owin's helper method, like so:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expirationTimeInMinutes),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
    });
```

And in all applications using this cookie, I have the following config in the web.config file:

```
<machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" />
```

As I understand, this configuration allows the applications to decrypt the same cookie.

In the MVC6 application I'm setting it up to use the cookies like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
  {
    //options.AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/login");
    //options.Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
  });
```

OK, here's my problem the configuration is already different, as I don't know to specify the provider nor the authentication type.

After, I'd have to config the decryption key, but as I understand MVC 6 doesn't have a web.config file. So how can I achieved this?

Comment: Are those two websites in same domain name?

Comment: yes, they are in the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: this answer is applicable to RC2 only, which should be released mid-May. It may work with RC1, but would require more work.

---

You can use the new `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` package to make the OWIN/Katana cookies middleware use the new serialization format and the new data protection stack used by ASP.NET Core (the other way around would be much harder, and definitely not recommended):

**OWIN/Katana app**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Create a new data protection provider with a unique app
        // name shared by both your OWIN/Katana and ASP.NET Core apps:
        var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("your app name");

        // Create a protector compatible with the ASP.NET Core cookies middleware.
        // Replace the second argument ("Cookies") by the authentication scheme
        // used by your ASP.NET Core cookies middleware if necessary.
        var protector = provider.CreateProtector(
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
            "Cookies", "v2");

        // Set TicketDataFormat to force the OWIN/Katana cookies middleware
        // to use the new serialization format used by ASP.NET Core:
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(new DataProtectorShim(protector))
        });
    }
}
```

---

**ASP.NET Core app**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataProtection(options =>
        {
            // Force the ASP.NET Core data protection stack to use
            // the name shared with your OWIN/Katana app.
            options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "your app name";
        });
    }
}
```

You should be able to remove the `machineKey` node in your `web.config` if you're only using it for the cookies middleware, as the OWIN/Katana cookies middleware will now use the new data protection stack, that doesn't rely on machine keys but on a key ring persisted on the machine (by default, in either the registry or in a special folder).

If your apps are deployed on different machines, I'd recommend synchronizing the key rings across your machines. You can read [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798591/542757) for more information.

Comment: Is there a nightly build I can try this?

Comment: You can use the aspnetcirelease feed to try the pre-release RC2 builds, but note that VS won't play nicely with these new packages (at least, until the new CLI tooling is released): https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcirelease

Comment: thanks. For the moment, all I need is a POC that the new AspNetCore will work with our existing applications.

Comment: It will, assuming you can update your existing apps to use the new serialization/data protection blocks.

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks, I'll try this later this afternoon.

Comment: I installed the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop from the feed you gave me, but I can 't find the namespaces that contain the classes DataProtectionProvider, AspNetTicketDataFormat and DataProtectorShim. I only found the interface IDataProtectionProvider

Comment: Same namespace as the package name. You can take a look at the source code to confirm it: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop

Comment: @vintem did you have a chance to confirm it worked as expected?

Comment: I haven't yet. Will do that next week.

Comment: I was not able to make this work. I used the same text for the application name but I'm receiving an 401 error on the asp.net core app. Also, I think there's no more provider.Create, only provider.CreateProtector which accepts a porpose, but I can't specify the the version of the provider.

Comment: The `Create`/`CreateProtector` is of course a typo, thanks for mentioning it. What you call "the version of the provider" is itself a purpose string, not a separate argument. Not sure why your ASP.NET Core app wouldn't work, since you only update the application name. It's quite obvious, but note that you'll have to re-authenticate when changing this setting.

Comment: I set up a breakpoint on the line options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "your app name", and the application never stopped there. Is that right?

Comment: Obviously no, it's not. But without seeing your final code, it's hard to say.

Comment: I have created a new Mvc Core application from scratch using VS2015 Community. I have selected no authentication as the authentication method and I have pasted the code in your example inside the Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method. I've changed the text for the ApplicationDiscriminator and added an Authorize attribute to the HomeController. That's all.

Comment: The configuration delegate is called at the last moment, when the data protection stack is invoked to protect or unprotect something. You must configure the cookies middleware and issue an authentication cookie to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend moving to OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect to authenticate once between your multiple applications, but barring that, what you will want to do is look at the Data Protection API.

- **Configuring Data Protection:**

  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html
- **Understanding how the default settings work:**

  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings.html

In order to obtain configuration values to use with the API, instead of `web.config` you may use one of the following approaches:

- a `.json` file or some other type of file that is deployed as part of an automated deployment process and conditionally loaded when your app starts up
- environment variables configured on the server, possibly in `applicationHost.config` for IIS for that application pool (requires IIS 10.0 or greater for app pool environment variables,  or if you are using the HttpPlatformHandler/AspNetCoreModule you can configure environment variables for that)
- Whatever else your imagination can come up with

You can read more about possible options for configuration at this documentation page:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

I got an easier solution (for my case) on ASP.NET Core side - no need to modify the ASP.NET 4 side:

I just built a simple IDataProtector (like the shim above), which does the following in Unprotect method:

```
public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
{
    // ... call the Unprotect method of the "shimmed" protector,
    // you'll get back the bytes

    // now make the Owin serializer to deserialize the old format

    Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer owinSerializer =
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer();

    Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket owinTicket = owinSerializer.Deserialize(cookie);

    // now build the ticket for the new format

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket coreTicket = new
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket(
            new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(owinTicket.Identity), 
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties(owinTicket.Properties.Dictionary), 
            _purpose);

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.TicketSerializer coreSerializer = 
        new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.TicketSerializer();

    // and return the new format, serialized - this will work

    return coreSerializer.Serialize(coreTicket);
}
```