# Shared cookie authentication between ASP.NET Core RC2 and .NET 4.5.1 apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, owin, asp.net-core-mvc

We have two .NET-apps running shared cookie authentication. One is an ASP.NET Core RC1 app, and the other is a classic .NET 4.5.1 app.

This is currently set up using the outdated `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.Interop` in the `Configuration` method of `Startup.cs`:

This works fine, but is no supported method for RC2.

How can we get going with shared cookie authentication for RC2?

Comment: I hope you can figure this out. I am in the same boat of needing to pass cookies from RC2 to 4.6.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining https://github.com/GrabYourPitchforks/aspnet5-samples/tree/dev/CookieSharing and [Sharing authentication cookie among Asp.Net Core 1 (MVC6) and MVC 5 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094782/sharing-authentication-cookie-among-asp-net-core-1-mvc6-and-mvc-5-applications) I was able to come up with a working solution. I have no idea if this is the "correct" way to to it, but it works, so here it goes:

1. Use the nuget-package  `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop 1.0.0-rc2-final` in both of the applications.
2. Create a `TicketDataFormat` using  `DataProtectionProvider` specifying the same location on disk for the encryption keys, as well as the same purpose.
3. Configure cookie authentication the owin way in both of the applications. Specify the same `CookieName` and `TicketDataFormat`:

.NET 4.5.1, in the Configure method of `Startup.cs`:

```
var authenticationType = "Cookies";
var cookieName = "myCookieName";
var cookieEncryptionKeyPath= "C:/mypath";

var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(cookieEncryptionKeyPath));
var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", authenticationType, "v2");
var ticketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(new DataProtectorShim(dataProtector));

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(authenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
            CookieName = cookieName,
            TicketDataFormat = ticketDataFormat
        });
```

.NET CORE RC2 in the Configure method of `Startup.cs`:

```
var authenticationType = "Cookies";
var cookieName = "myCookieName";
var cookieEncryptionKeyPath= "C:/mypath";

var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(cookieEncryptionKeyPath));
var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", authenticationType, "v2");
var ticketFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);


app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    CookieName = options.CookieName,
                    CookieDomain = options.CookieDomain,
                    TicketDataFormat = ticketFormat
                });
```