# Decrypt ".AspNetCore.Session" cookie in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In Asp.Net core, a cookie is created when you configure your app to `app.UseSession()`. 
By default the cookie is called ".AspNetCore.Session". Its value identifies the session to be used. Currently, I'm saving my session data on a sql server. I need to know the decrypted value of ".AspNetCore.Session" so that I can lookup the session in the database.

Is there a way to decrypt this value? I know ASP.NET must do it behind the scenes somehow.

Comment: I wonder if it is the same encrypt/decrypt functionality as Forms Security. Perhaps whatever FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() is using might work or at least worth a try.

Comment: It is an `IDataProtector` followed by base64-encoding. To decrypt, you will first need to base64-decode into a byte array, then apply part of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37543433/1132334. The "secret" is this part: `CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the direction @dlatikay. From the link you provided, what do I put in C:\mypath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to extract the private `Pad` function from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`, but I was able to get what I needed:

```
public class DiscussionController : Controller
{   
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;        

    public DiscussionController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        var protectorPurpose = "whatever purpose you want";

        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(protectorPurpose);
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {     
       HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(".AspNetCore.Session", out string cookieValue);

       var protectedData = Convert.FromBase64String(Pad(cookieValue));

       var unprotectedData = _dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedData);

       var humanReadableData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unprotectedData);

        return Ok();
    }

    private string Pad(string text)
    {
        var padding = 3 - ((text.Length + 3) % 4);
        if (padding == 0)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return text + new string('=', padding);
    }    
}
```

The `Pad` function was taken from: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/87629bbad906e9507026692904b6bcb5021cdd33/src/Middleware/Session/src/CookieProtection.cs#L61-L69

Comment: thanks for your constructive comment @LeoGurdian.
The link and code have been updated.

Answer (score 3):

The [session source](https://github.com/aspnet/Session) has everything, but you should need to know it, [ISessionStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/ISessionStore.cs) and [IDistributedSessionStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/DistributedSessionStore.cs) gives you a sessionkey to use.

Rather than make an assumption about the cookie format, what is stopping you from using the store APIs?

Comment: ISessionStore only has one public member defined which is the Create method.  So how does one use it to get the `SessionKey` which is the key to the sql server table that stores the session data?