# How to extract the session key from asp net core SessionMiddleware

Tags: asp.net-core, session, .net-core, redis, session-cookies

I'm working on project which uses Redis as a distributed cache for storing my session data. My application should check first if the cache have the session object, if not it should get the data from the DB.
The problem is that I can't get access to the session key itself and the SessionMiddleware uses the session key as a key in Redis Cache.
I came up with some solutions:

- To Use Session.LoadAsync() method to update the app session state and check if the Session.Keys hold some data.
- To Find a way to decrypt the cookie session, which is send with the request and obtain the key from it
- To Create custom modification for the SessionMiddleware and override the default behaviour to extract the key session

But I wander if there is a better, simpler more elegant way to get this session key in app and make a query to Redis if the key session exists. Is there some Service, Manager, etc. which extract the key session from incoming request and makes it available ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution to my problem provided by "John-Luke Laue" in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40685514/12543959.

Important !
The solution is ok but you can still get a error:

```
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 protectedPayload, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
```

The problem is in one place, the value of variable purpose, required in CreateProtector() as parameter of type string:

```
    var protectorPurpose = "whatever purpose you want";

    _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(protectorPurpose);
```

Because the encryption of session key is made in SessionMiddleware, the correct value should be "SessionMiddleware" of type string , and the code should look like this:

```
    _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(nameof(SessionMiddleware));
```