# SignalR Authorize attribute does not work with cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-core

I am using AspNetCore and the cookie middleware for authentication which I set up like this...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = Constants.AuthenticationScheme,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/")
});
```

I am successfully authenticating using a login form and then redirect to a controller which is marked with an [Authorize] attribute.

The controller then loads a page which has the javascript signalR client in which connects to the hub.

However when I add the signalR [Authorize] attribute. I get a 401 Unauthorized from the server.

How can I make signalR recognize the authentication cookie? I can see that it has been passed the cookie in Context.RequestCookies.

Failing that how could i manually decrypt the cookie and set the User myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by decrypting the cookie myself, however I would be very interested in a better way.

I created a helper class for generating the authentication ticket format with help from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529741/shared-cookie-authentication-between-asp-net-core-rc2-and-net-4-5-1-apps)

```
public static class SecurityHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the format for the security cookie used to encrypt and decrpyt cookie
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The app service provider</param>
    /// <returns>The authentication ticket format</returns>
    public static ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> GetTicketFormat(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var authenticationType = "Cookies";
        var protectionProvider = services.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
        var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", authenticationType, "v2");
        return new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
    }
}
```

And told the cookie middleware to use this ticket format in my startup.cs class...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
            TicketDataFormat = SecurityHelper.GetTicketFormat(app.ApplicationServices)
});
```

And then with the help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) article created my own signalr authentication attribute to decrypt the cookie and set the user principal.

```
/// <summary>
/// Attribute to have signalr hubs authenticate
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthorizeHubUsersAttribute :  AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Decrpyt the authentication cookie and set the user principal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hubDescriptor">The hub descriptor</param>
    /// <param name="request">The request object</param>
    /// <returns>If the user is aythenticated</returns>
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, HttpRequest request)
    {
        var cookie = request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];
        var ticketFormat = SecurityHelper.GetTicketFormat(request.HttpContext.RequestServices);
        var authenticationTicket = ticketFormat.Unprotect(cookie);
        request.HttpContext.User = authenticationTicket.Principal; 

        return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check the user is authenticated
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The user principal</param>
    /// <returns>If the user is aythenticated</returns>
    protected override bool UserAuthorized(IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user?.Identity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Then all I had to do was decorate my hub class with the attribute

```
[AuthorizeHubUsersAttribute()]
public class GameMessageHub : Hub<IGameMessageHub> {
 ....
}
```

I couldn't find a way of injecting dependencies into a signalr attribute, but if anyone figures it out I'd like to know.